# DES Weak Keys - Double Encryption

Tags: des, openssl

I know there are 4 known weak keys, their value and that double encryption using one of the weak keys should give back the plain text.

I implemented this in OpenSSL. I have a plain text $m$ in a file `plain.txt` and compute $y = DES_k(m)$ where $k$ is a weak key. Then I compute $y' = DES_k(y)$. Instead of getting $m$ I get only a portion of it and the rest is part of $y$.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't get the expected result, then you are doing it wrong; most probably, use wrong mode of operation and/or wrong padding. You can get the expected result with openssl as

```
openssl enc -e -des-ecb -in plain.txt -out cipher1.txt -nopad -K 0101010101010101 -iv 0
openssl enc -e -des-ecb -in cipher1.txt -out cipher2.txt -nopad -K 0101010101010101 -iv 0
```

`plain.txt` file size should be multiple of 8 (8 bytes is DES block size), and `plain.txt` and `cipher2.txt` files should be identical.

Comment: I'm almost there. I get an error that says "Data not multiple of block length", but when I look at cipher2.txt, more of the plaintext is there, but not all of it. My plaintext file has 19 characters (includes spaces). Is this related to the padding? How do I force the data to be a multiple of the block length?

Comment: Eureka. The mode should be ofb. Off to research why. Hints welcomed. ;) Thank you!

Comment: @planejane  Eureaka is wrong. You should use ECB mode without padding (-nopad option), and plaintext file size should be multiple of 8 (8 bytes is DES block size); OFB mode decryption is the same operation as encryption, so OFB double encryption with the same key is in fact encryption+decryption, and it works with **any** key, not with a weak key only.

Comment: Ok then. When I use ECB mode, only 16 of the 19 characters are displayed. Why? How do I force the data to be a multiple of the block length? I used your suggested oppenssl command precisely and don't get an exact copy of the original plaintext.

Comment: file size should be multiple of 8, so add some characters (dot, spaces, anything you like) to the end of file to make the file size multiple of 8.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I assume that when implementing, there should be some handling to ensure the message length is a multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: @planejane: that handling is [_padding_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)). You can see it at work: specify `-e -des-ecb` for encryption and `-e -des-ecb -nopad` for decryption; then examine the deciphered plaintext with something that can view arbitrary bytes, like `hexdump`.